# Measurability of the weak completion of an orthogonal representation

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, rt.representation-theory, measure-theory

Let $G$ be a locally compact group and let $\pi$ be a strongly continuous orthogonal representation of $G$ in a real Hilbert space $H$. Denote by $E$ the real Hausdorff locally convex space obtained by endowing $H$ with its weak topology and by $\widehat E$ it completion, and algebraically identify the topological dual of $\widehat E$ with $H$.

From $\pi$ can be obtained a representation $\widehat\pi$ of $G$ in $\widehat E$ by defining $\widehat\pi(g)$ to be the unique continuous linear mapping from $\widehat E$ to itself extending $\pi(g)$. I am interested in knowing if this representation $\widehat\pi$ is of good quality.

Is it necessarily true that for every $\widehat x\in\widehat E$ and every $y\in H$ the mapping $g\mapsto\langle y,\widehat\pi(g)\widehat x\rangle$ from $G$ to $\mathbf R$ is measurable with respect to the Haar measure of $G$?